# EC2 vertical scaling in Auto-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services

What are the methods/services/best practices on AWS to vertically scale EC2 instances in Auto-scaling group. I found that Ops Automator V2, but their Github scripts are more than 2 years old. Not sure its still relevant ? (I'm planning to automate this with Cloudformation)

Comment: Vertical scaling is rarely done, horizontal is much more common. I don't work in EC2 very often, but I'd probably look at either a combination of autoscaling groups and launch configurations, or perhaps use a custom lambda function.